# Highcharts returning error 15 but the graph is correct?

Tags: php, javascript, graph, highcharts

I have been at this for hours and I have no idea what's wrong.  It displays the correct graph but I can't hover on any of the points.  I've read through my var_dump() and all my records are in order.  Am I converting the dates wrong at some point?

What my graph looks like (Which is correct): http://screencloud.net/v/qrSS

The error I'm getting: "Highcharts error #15: www.highcharts.com/errors/15"

> Highcharts expects data to be sorted
>
> This happens when you are trying to create a line series or a stock chart where the data is not sorted in ascending X order. For performance reasons, Highcharts does not sort the data, instead it is required that the implementer pre-sorts the data.

My console: http://screencloud.net/v/qWHo

My highcharts code

```
        $.post('/card/read_graph_json', inputs, function(data) {
            json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'spline'
                },
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        animation: false
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: '{{ $card->name }}'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: null
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                        month: '%b',
                        year: '%b'
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    },
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        var monthNames = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ],
                            date = new Date(this.x);

                        return '<strong>'+ this.series.name +'</strong><br/>'+ monthNames[date.getMonth()] + '. ' + date.getDay() + ', ' + date.getFullYear() +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                },
                series: [json]
            });
        });
```

My php that creates the JSON

```
public function contact_records($contact_id, $number_past_entries = 6, $reverse = false) 
{
        // Pull 15 records from db and order them by date created "Y-m-d H:i:s" 
        return $this->has_many('Record')
            ->where_deleted(0)
            ->where_contact_id($contact_id)
            ->order_by('created_at', 'desc')
            ->take($number_past_entries)
            ->get();
}

public function post_read_graph_json()
{
    $contact_id = Input::get('contact_id');
    $tracker = Tracker::find(Input::get('tracker_id'));
    $card = Card::find(Input::get('card_id'));
    $serie = array();

    if ($tracker != null && $card != null) {
        Cookie::forever("default_graph_tracker_id", $tracker->id);
        $data = array();

        // This is where my records come from
        $records = $card->contact_records($contact_id, 15);

        // Create the serie
        foreach ($records as $record) {
            $data[] = array(
                strtotime($record->created_at) * 1000,
                floatval($record->read_tracker_value($tracker->id)->value)
            );
        }

        $serie = array(
            'name' => $tracker->name,
            'data' => $data
        );
    }

    return json_encode($serie);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this function

```
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter=array();
    $ret=array();
    reset($array);
    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
        $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
    }
    asort($sorter);
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
    }
    $array=$ret;
}
```

Updated tis part of my code

```
        $data = array();
        foreach ($records as $record) {
            $data[] = array(
                'time' => strtotime($record->created_at) * 1000,
                'value' => floatval($record->read_tracker_value($tracker->id)->value)
            );
        }

        aasort($data, 'time');

        $new_data = array();
        foreach ($data as $record) {
            $new_data[] = array(
                $record['time'],
                $record['value']
            );
        }

        $serie = array(
            'name' => $tracker->name,
            'data' => $new_data
        );
```

ta da!

Comment: It's not so easy, if you can avoid sorting it'd be much better, sorting is not a cheap operation, it's rather time expensive. If you have large data structure you'll clearly loose performance.

Comment: This option is not bad, its being sorted on the server side also so its better that sorting on the client. If your data set is huge then break it into sections. The answer is good. Also if you want to avoid sorting simply suppress the error.